# Fresh Install SQLite3 in Django 1.8

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

I named an app incorrectly in Django which I have renamed but I'm now getting migration errors for non-existent parent nodes. So I'd like to fresh install. Is there a django native way of doing this or best practice? At this stage I think I'll just start a new app and copy the db over.

Comment: Why not just delete the sqlite file?

Comment: Perfect, cheers for that.

Comment: @user20357 you should mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. That will help future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just delete the `db.sqlite3` file in the project directory**

Recently in my django project, I faced similar problems. Initially I created two classes in my models.py, then after a custom migration for populating the database with initial data, I needed to make three classes in models.py, where the third table would need to be populated with data in the second migration. This caused similar problems. I simply deleted the `db.sqlite3` file in the project directory, backed up my custom migrations, made necessary changes to my `models.py`, then ran `makemigrations` followed by a `migrate`. Everything went just fine. Hope it helps.